# Chart.js display x axis labels ON ticks in bar chart, not between

Tags: chart.js

I have this chart:

[image: bar chart]

...which is displaying exactly how I want it to with one exception... The data in the bars is for between the two times in the x axis... so all the labels need shifting to lie on the grid lines, not between them as default for a bar chart. So the red and blue bar is data between 8:00 and 9:00. I hope I've explained that clearly enough.

I'm trawling through the Chart.js docs and it just doesn't seem like this is possible! I know I could change my labels to be, for example, 8pm - 9pm, but that seems a much more visually clunky way of doing it. Is there a way anyone know of achieving this? Ideally there would be another '12am' on the last vertical grid line too.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw the tick lables at the desired position directly on to the `canvas` using the [Plugin Core API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#plugin-core-api). It offers number of hooks that may be used for performing custom code. In below code snippet, I use the `afterDraw` hook to draw my own labels on the `xAxis`.

```js
const hours = ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06'];
const values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 6, 0];

const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  plugins: [{
    afterDraw: chart => {      
      var xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var tickDistance = xAxis.width / (xAxis.ticks.length - 1);
      xAxis.ticks.forEach((value, index) => {
        if (index > 0) {
          var x = -tickDistance + tickDistance * 0.66 + tickDistance * index;
          var y = chart.height - 10;
          chart.ctx.save();        
          chart.ctx.fillText(value == '0am' ? '12am' : value, x, y);
          chart.ctx.restore();
        }
      });      
    }
  }],
  data: {
    labels: hours,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: values,
      categoryPercentage: 0.99,
      barPercentage: 0.99,
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },   
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          parser: 'HH',
          unit: 'hour',
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'Ha'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'Ha'
        },
        gridLines: {
          offsetGridLines: true
        },
        ticks: {
          min: moment(hours[0], 'HH').subtract(1, 'hours'),
          fontColor: 'white'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect! Will try this and report back! Thanks!